# How to place canvas with drawings inside certain column of a ListView control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to place canvas with drawings inside certain column of a `ListView` control ?

I have this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Canvas Width="60" Height="20" Background="Red" ClipToBounds="True" >
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Graph}" />
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

and:

```
var canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Children.Add(new Ellipse(){});
var items = new ObservableCollection<LvItem>() { new LvItem(){ Graph = canvas} };
myListView.ItemsSource = items;
```

but it shows `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` as a text, and not the canvas itself with its drawings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working, check example below.

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="myListView" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Grap">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas Width="60" Height="50" Background="Red" ClipToBounds="True" >
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Graph}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>                    
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

LvItem class:

```
class LvItem
{
    public Canvas Graph { get; set; }
}
```

Code-behind:

```
var canvas = new Canvas();
canvas.Children.Add(new Ellipse() { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow) });
var canvas2 = new Canvas();
canvas2.Children.Add(new Ellipse() { Width = 50, Height = 50, Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue) });
var items = new ObservableCollection<LvItem>() { new LvItem() { Graph = canvas }, new LvItem() { Graph = canvas2 } };
myListView.ItemsSource = items;
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: it's embarrassing... I didn't notice for a long time that I had `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Graph}"` in the `GridViewColumn` attributes... thanks you for your confirmation that it does work, and letting me focus on finding my bug...